# How did these "not-an-answer" flags get declined?

Tags: support, flags

Three hours ago, I flagged an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362458/redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain) as "not an answer". I don't have access to moderator tools to show you that answer and don't remember its exact content.

My flag was declined by a moderator because (s)he "found no evidence".

When I flagged the answer, it already had six down votes. By the time my flag was declined, the answer has already been deleted.

So my question is: How can there be no evidence that this answer was "not an answer" and why my flag was declined? Or should I care about declined flags at all?

Actually I'm wondering: The last time my (few not helpful) flags got all declined instead of disputed. Probably since I reached 3k rep. I'd like to know the reason for that too.

Comment: This is the link to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36661654/1743880. It was later deleted by a moderator. My guess is that this was a simple mistake. I pinged the moderator in chat, so he might come and clarify.

Comment: It's not spam, just NAA. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29981243#29981243

Comment: thx for the answer link, guess it was a mistake, too.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake. This was discussed in the SOCVR chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29981254#29981254

Comment: 4 people flagged it as spam and 4 as NAA; probably what should have happened is the spam flags should have been declined and the NAA flags marked helpful. Of course, we need people to be careful about their use of the spam flag, and they clearly weren't here. Sorry the OP got mixed up in that.

Comment: I see 2 declined flags out of your last 55 flags cast. You're going to have to be more specific about what you're referring to. 1 decline was recent, the other was at the beginning of April.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker maybe it's just coincidence, and I don't have a specific record, but I know that my last 4 or 5 _not helpful_ flags were _declined_ and _none disputed_ while some month ago all my not helpful flags (except one wrong spam flag) were _disputed_ instead of _declined_.

Comment: @RenéVogt - I made a mistake by declining everything (when I should have declined only spam flags) . Sorry about that.

Comment: @TheLostMind no problem, mistakes happen, I just wanted to know what went wrong

Comment: I don't see how a "support" question can be closed as unreproducible. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 13):

Human error.

The moderator in question (not me) wanted to decline just the spam flags on the post, but declined all flags by accident. It happens. Sorry about that!

Comment: And I missed that TheLostMind had already replied in the comments. :-P Can't help you now, buddy!